# Пожалуйста найти ошибку. По возможности дорешать задачу

Tags: c++

Дана квадратная матрица. Если в i-ой строке матрицы элемент принадлежащий главной диагонали отрицателен, то заменить этот элемент суммой элементов i-ой строки; в противном случае-произведением элементов i-ой строки. Элементы главной диагонали (измененные)вывести в одномерный массив в порядке возрастания. Вывести исходную и преобразованную матрицы, полученный массив.Вот собственно задача, я написал такой вот код, но выводит какие-то космические числа. Еще когда пытаюсь вывести преобразованную матрицу, она почему то выводится в столбик. Пожалуйста помогите.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <cmath>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    setlocale(0, "");
    srand(unsigned(time(NULL)));
    double sum = 0, proizv = 1;
    int N, M, fv, lv;

    cout << "_________________________________________________________________________"<< endl;
    cout << "Введите размер матрицы: ";
    cin >> N >> M;
    cout << "Введите нижний предел рандомных чисел" << endl;
    cin >> fv;
    cout << "Введите верхний предел рандомных чисел" << endl;
    cin >> lv;
    int** A = new int*[N];
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        A [i] = new int[M];

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < M; j++)
            A[i][j] = fv + rand() % (lv - fv + 1);;
                    
    
    cout << "Вот матрица:" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < M; j++)
            cout << A[i][j] << " ";
        cout << endl;
     }
    cout << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)   
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < M; j++)
        {
            if (A[i][i] < 0)
            {
                A[i][i] = sum + A[i][j];
            }
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)   
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < M; j++)
        {
            if (A[i][i] >= 0);
            {
                proizv *= A[i][j];
                A[i][i] = proizv * A[i][j];
            }   
        }
    }
    cout << "Преобразованная матрица:" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
       for (int j = 0; j < M; j++)
       {
           cout << A[i][j] << "\t";
           cout << "\n";
       }
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Вы же идёте по главной диагонали. Вам не нужен вложенный цикл.

Comment: Не по делу, но по предупреждениям компилятора - зачем `sum` - `double`, если потом вы его опять првращаете в `int`? Как и `proizv`. И еще - `if(A[i][i]>=0); { proizv*=A[i][j];` - тут точно нужна точка с запятой **перед** фигурной скобкой? Ну, а огромные числа - обычно что-то не инициализировано... или переполнилось...

Comment: Квадратная матрица подразумевает, что достаточно одного размера - N. sum и proizv нужно инициализировать перед каждой строкой, а лучше вообще удалить,  и инициализировать A[i][i]

Comment: @Harry Точку с запятой требовал сам компилятор))) А тогда 'sum' и 'proizv' сделать сразу 'int'?

Comment: @MBo Если не сделать вложенный цикл, то не дает посчитать сумму или произведение, идентификатор j не определен..

Comment: @EOF Не могу понять ваши изменения.

Comment: Я просто отредактировал код. Сделал его читаемым. Я не менял его смысл. Только изменение внешнего вида

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот эту часть кода:

```
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)   
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < M; j++)
        {
            if (A[i][i] < 0)
            {
                A[i][i] = sum + A[i][j];
            }
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)   
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < M; j++)
        {
            if (A[i][i] >= 0);
            {
                proizv *= A[i][j];
                A[i][i] = proizv * A[i][j];
            }   
        }
    }
```

можно заменить на:

```
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
{
    if (A[i][i] < 0)
    {
        int sum = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
        {
            sum += A[i][j];
        }
        A[i][i] = sum;
    }
    else if (A[i][i] > 0)
    {
        int product = 1;
        for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
        {
            product *= A[i][j];
        }
        A[i][i] = product;
    }
    else
    {
        A[i][i] = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо. Но я не знаю пока, как работают функции

Comment: @Zhenyadze отредактировал

Comment: Огромное Вам спасибо! Можно еще вопрос, пожалуйста? Почему при попытке вывода преобразованной матрицы она выводится в столбик?

Comment: @Zhenyadze `cout << "\n";` должно быть после внутреннего цикла, а не в нём.

Comment: Теперь выводится в строчку) А как сделать что бы он принял вид матрицы?

Comment: @Zhenyadze после внутреннего, а не после внешнего. Также как вы выводите в первый раз

Comment: Благодарю от всей души, Вы сильно помогли мне.